# How to keep user logged in using Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router, vuejs3

I am managing performing a login and the login state using `Vuex`. It is a standard procedure of:

1. User submits their login details on a form
2. The form dispatches a `Vuex` action to make an `axios` API call to a Node/Express endpoint `/api/login` with the credentials
3. The response from the API if successful will send back the user's data which is stored in the `state.user` object through a `setUser` mutation. A flag of `state.user.isLoggedIn` is also set to `true`.
4. A JWT access token is sent to the user's browser and stored in a secure cookie to use over and over again until it expires. If it expires, a refresh token is used to generate a new JWT access token.
5. The site's header displays the user's login information .e.g name

The above all works as expected. However if the user refreshes their browser, then `Vuex` state gets emptied and the site header no longer shows the user information. To overcome this I stored `state.user` into `localStorage` in the browser as persisted data and repopulate the `Vuex` store using the data in `localStorage` on page refresh. If the user logs out, the `localStorage` is cleared.

There are many routes that require checking if the user is logged in. I cannot rely on `localStorage` because it can be manipulated by the user.  If the user deletes their cookies which contains a JWT, then `localStorage` is not being emptied and the site header still displays their log-in information. Therefore I need to do an API call on almost every page to check if the user is logged in and if not then to delete the `localStorage` as well.

My question is:

1. Where do I perform a log-in check every time a page/view is accessed? Is it whenever the Vue `app` is mounted or within `vue-router` using the [`beforeEach`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) navigation guard?
2. If I use `beforeEach` in `vue-router`, is it going to crash the site by making an API call to `/api/login` every time a user changes route? Is it normal practice to do this on every route?
3. Are there any other alternative patterns to keeping track of if the user is logged in or not?

Answer (score 3):

Application decisions like this tend to be subjective because every application is different, with different requirements and different architectures. It sounds like this is a single page application, so I'll go from there.

First, the fact that your JWT is set up and working is great - that can be a lot of hard work, so be proud that you made it that far.

If your application has certain pages that are accessible without first being logged in (like a login page, or an access denied page, etc.), then you have to consider that in the design as well. In this case, a `beforeEach` route guard is the perfect solution to keep a route from loading or to catch those not-logged-in users before they attempt to request content that will likely just give them an error.

You probably shouldn't have to make an API call to the server each time the user navigates to a new page. That would probably be a little slow. Because your application uses JWT, complete with refresh tokens, you should be able to rely on them, so that if a user is logged in, they will continue to be logged in until they close their browser and walk away.

This is why you should not use localStorage. When a tab closes or even after a reboot, the user will still appear to be logged in. **Instead of using `localStorage`, use `sessionStorage`** - [Helpful MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

Now, the login event to retrieve the `user` object should only happen once per browser tab, but stay active during the visit.

I wonder why you don't just request a new `user` object from the server when the browser is refreshed. It's not strange to force a re-check to the server for a full page load. Doing that would mean you wouldn't have to use anything outside of Vuex to store the user's state

Next, is there a way to check the validity of their JWT during the navigation event? Depending on the way you handle the JWT, you may have access to it, and can possibly decode it (like through the `oidc-client-js` library), and that way determine for yourself if the token is expired. However, if the token is expired, your token refresh system may just refresh it and not tell you about it.

You can also watch your HTTP requests and look out for 401 or 403 responses (however your back-end handles logged-out users), and direct the user back to the login screen if you see one of those. You can use Axios' global interceptors to catch them, or do it yourself if you centralized the location from where Axios is called.

Overall, you're on your way, and clearly have a good grasp on this. Great progress so far, having done probably 90% of the heavy lifting already.